# pass variable to subprocess.check_output python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a function named `generator(path):` in my `test.py` file.

I am calling `test.py` from another `.py` file using `subprocess.check_output()`.

How do I pass the value of `path` to my generator function while calling the file inside `subprocess.check_output()`?

Comment: Why are you calling the file inside subprocess when you can import the py file directly and use the function?

Comment: i'm actually using this method to call from within my tensorflow/models/research/slim folder and while impoting i'm getting error of no module named datasets.